# Find all Python packages depending on a linux system library

Tags: python, linux, pip, dependencies, conda

Let's assume scenario where a security scan revealed a High vulnerability in a certain linux system library.

How to find all python packages (out of many installed using `pip` and `conda`) that require this system library?

In other words, `pipdeptree`, but returning system libraries.

- More info. As a form of risk mitigation we are going to temporarily uninstall the affected python package(s) to get rid of the vulnerable system library. We can be sure that the system library is not required for correct operation of the underlying operating system, because the vulnerability is not present in the base image containing just the operating system. We cannot keep the vulnerable library installed but just disabled/blocked - the build-time security scan must pass cleanly (i.e. without the library installed).

Comment: Just do `chmod a-r <path-to-lib>`

Comment: Good idea to prevent access (possibly execution would do as well?) to the system library. It would be effective from a security viewpoint, but it still may not allow us to pass the security scan (which is performed at the Docker container level after the image is built but before it is run).

Comment: The problem with the `chmod` solution is that the security scanner will run the container as root, so even if we have removed all three permissions (`chmod -r-w-x`), scanner as root will still retain the ability to `cat` the contents of the file and thus would be able to find the vulnerability, even though regular users are blocked from accessing the library.

Comment: rename the lib.

Comment: The question of finding all system dependencies of a python package still remains unanswered, but I have found a safe workaround in my specific situation, using conda-installed patched version of the system lib.

Comment: If `liba` is buggy and `libb` depends on it, and Python package `a` depnds on Python package `b` and in turn Python package `b` depends on `libb` , what now? It's complicated!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this particular package had a `conda`-installable python package, with the same name and depending on the vulnerable system library, in which the system dependency was already patched.

So the first step was to upgrade the python package using `conda`, which also upgraded the system binary in the `conda-`specific folder (`/opt/conda/bin/<package>`):

```
conda install -y <package>
```

However, the same library in the user-level location (`/usr/bin/`) was still vulnerable, so I had to overwrite it with the `conda`-patched version (I inspected the diff in the library source repo to ensure the patch was minor):

```
rm /usr/bin/<package> && ln -s /opt/conda/bin/<package> /usr/bin/<package>
```

Moreover, because the initial security scan was run also before the conda patch could be performed, I had to add the CVE to the whitelist (but only for this docker image covered by the initial scan, not for the final image scanned after the patch).